# Which Nsight version that can be used CUDA5.5, in VisualStudio2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda, nvidia, nsight

I am using CUDA5.5 at the VisualStudio2010 on Windows7 64bit.

I'm going to install a Nsight VisualStudioEdition 
and I would like to debug the code of CUDA.

The Nsight3.1 that I found on the site of nVidia is like the latest version,
It had been described as corresponds to the VisualStudio2012.

Nsight3.1 work? CUDA5.5, in VisualStudio2010?
Also, is there a version of Nsight that can be used CUDA5.5, in VisualStudio2010?

Please let me know which version of nSight that can be used CUDA5.5, in VisualStudio2010?

---

The following message is displayed in the item of "Nsight C + + AMP Debugger" when you try to install the Nsight.
This does not it? Have failed to install?

**Nsight C++ AMP Debugger**
　Nsight C++ AMP Debugger for Visual Studio 2012 will not be installed.
　Requirement not met:Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 was not found.
　Nsight C++ AMP Target Support for MSVSMON will be installed
　warning:Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 MSVMON.exe was not found.

Comment: I'm using Nsight 3.1 with Visual Studio 2010 and either CUDA 5.0 or CUDA 5.5 on several systems with no problem. I think that what you have read should be meant as Nsight is now compatible _also_ with Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: @JackOLantern: Add that as an answer and it will get upvoted, the question will disappear off the unanswered list, and we can all move on....

Comment: Thank you for your replying.                                      The following message is displayed in the item of "Nsight C + + AMP Debugger" when I try to install the Nsight.Nsight C++ AMP Debugger
　Nsight C++ AMP Debugger for Visual Studio 2012 will not be installed.
　Requirement not met
　Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 was not found.
　Nsight C++ AMP Target Support for MSVSMON will be installed
　warning:Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 MSVMON.exe was not found.
so, This does not it? Have failed to install?

Comment: @talonmies I have converted the comment to an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Nsight 3.1 with Visual Studio 2010 and either CUDA 5.0 or CUDA 5.5 on several systems with no problem.

Nsight is now compatible *also* with Visual Studio 2012, see

[Install Nsight Visual Studio Edition](https://developer.nvidia.com/install-nsight-visual-studio-edition)

if local debugging (host and target on same machine) is concerned.

Concerning Nsight C++ AMP Debugger, if you do not need it, you don't have to worry about this error message. If you have Visual Studio 2010, you will be able to perform CUDA and/or graphics debugging after the installation is complete, see

[getting the problem during the installation of nsight visual studio](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/529356/getting-the-problem-during-the-installation-of-nsight-visual-studio/)

Comment: Thank you Jack.   It was a great help. and now I'm using Nsight3.1 with Visual Studio 2010 and CUDA5.5 with no problem !